# Qual a quantidade apropriada de alterações para um commit?

Tags: git, versionamento, commit

Tenho percebido que, em muitos projetos públicos no [GitHub](https://github.com/), os *commits* costumam conter alterações muito pequenas. Há vários casos de *commits* com alterações em uma única linha de código. Em outros, há alterações apenas em comentários, não em código.

Eu não costumo trabalhar assim. Uso o [Git](http://git-scm.com/) localmente e evito fazer *commits* de alterações mínimas, normalmente são alterações substanciais. Em alguns casos, meus *commits* contém alterações em mais de 10 arquivos. Tenho me perguntado se isso é o ideal.

Qual é a quantidade apropriada de alterações para um único *commit*?

Comment: Várias perguntas boas geram algum grau de opinião com base na experiência de especialistas, mas as respostas a esta pergunta tenderão a ser quase que completamente baseadas em opiniões e não em fatos, referências ou experiência específica.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Não é ideal medir um *commit* pela quantidade de arquivo ou por sua percepção do tamanho das alterações.

No mundo ideal, um *commit* deveria conter uma, e somente uma, nova funcionalidade ou então uma única correção. Isso possibilita a rastreabilidade de impacto de cada alteração e um possível *rollback* desse commit no caso dele quebrar alguma coisa.

Por outro lado, se você unir as funcionalidades X, Y e Z num mesmo *commit* e a funcionalidade Z não for aprovada para a *release*, não seria possível reverter a alteração pela própria ferramenta. Seria necessário criar uma nova versão do sistema a partir da versão final e remover Z. Ou então criar uma nova *branch* e aplicar as mesmas alterações feitas em X e Y.

Para esse esquema ter um efeito ainda melhor, é interessante usar um *branch* diferente para cada funcionalidade. Após a implementação, o *commit* é feito na *branch* e a versão final do sistema é o *merge* de todas as funcionalidades selecionadas.

Eu não sei até que ponto levar isso, pois de forma pragmática você até pode juntar funcionalidades que são interdependentes, mas algo que os usuários mais experientes de GIT sempre dizem é para não ter medo de criar branches.

Um princípio importante e prático, é usar a ferramenta como for melhor para você e sua equipe organizarem o código. Em outras palavras: *use a ferramenta para ajudar o seu trabalho, não trabalhe em função da ferramenta*.

Answer (score 8):

A resposta simples é: Você escolhe.

A resposta completa seria: depende do sistema de versionamento que pretende usar.

O sistema mais usado é o [SemVer](http://semver.org/) que usa 3 parametros separados por pontos. Os parametros correspondem Major, Minor, Patch

> **MAJOR** nova versão quando a nova API é incompatível com a anterior,
>   **MINOR** quando se adicionam novos métodos que respeitam, e são compatíveis, com métodos anteriores
>   **PATCH** todos os remendos, correções que são exclusivamente para corrigir erros ou bugs no código sem adicionar novas features/métodos.

Assim se estiver a usar SEMVER, ou seja Semantic Versioning todos os patchs por menores que sejam devem incrementar o parametro patch e ter uma nova tag no git.

**Tem outro aspecto** que está ligado à facilidade de perceber e analizar os commits. Um commit deve ter mudanças relacionadas apenas com um assunto. Commits que mexem em *n* ficheiros e mudam muitos comportamentos são confusos e indesejáveis.

Comment: Interessante. Onde marco essa versão? Na mensagem do *commit*? `git commit -m "1.2.3"`?

Comment: @Andrey eu não costumo ligar mensagens de commits com tags, mas teste `$ git push <remote> tag <tagname>` ou somente `git push --follow-tags`

Answer (score 8):

> **TL / DR**: **Não existem regras.** Porém projetos *open source* -> presença de  *pull requests* e *patches* -> tendência de commits menores, que possam ser facilmente revisados por outros desenvolvedores. Projetos comerciais -> Tendência de *commits* maiores implementando todos os aspectos de determinada *feature* (mesmo que o desenvolvedor localmente faça vários *commits*). Novamente, não existem regras, mas pude observar esse diferença de comportamento na prática entre os dois tipos de projetos.

Enquanto não existem regras definidas, projetos *open source maduros* com vários colaboradores costumam trabalhar com uma granularidade mais fina de *commits*. Isso ocorre devido a própria natureza do projeto. Em projetos *open source* diversos desenvolvedores externos fazem *pull requests* e/ou submetem pequenos *patches* para arrumar pequenos bugs ou adicionar pequenas funcionalidades ao projeto. A ideia aqui é que os *commits* não só sejam representativos, mais autocontidos e facilmente revisáveis por um desenvolvedor do projeto. *Commits* menores são mais rápidos de revisar e dão menos dor de cabeça para quem vai integrar o seu código ao repositório principal (possivelmente muito tempo depois que você submeteu o *patch*).

Mesmo o time "central" de um projeto, com permissão para fazer *push* no repositório principal, costuma trabalhar com uma granularidade mais fina de *commits*. Grandes unidades de trabalho são geralmente bem subdivididas entre os diversos módulos, e posteriormente subdividas em tarefas menores. O resultado é que existem mais tarefas, cada qual mais "pontual"; logo são feitos mais *commits*, cada um com menos código.

Já em projetos comerciais é igualmente comum que um desenvolvedor faça vários pequenos *commits* locais (digamos, em um *branch* de *feature*), mas antes do *push* para o repositório principal, é prática comum fazer um de *squash* desses *commits*, dando a impressão de um único grande *commit* que resolveu determinada tarefa / problema. O ponto principal aqui é que a granularidade das tarefas são maiores, e há um esforço para tornar o repositório mais "limpo".

Cada estratégia possuiu suas vantagens. *Commits* frequentes e pequenos representam melhor o fluxo real de desenvolvimento, porém, granularidade mais grossa e reescrita de histórico tornam a árvore de *commit* mais "limpa". Existem bons argumentos da escola "Faça *commit* rápido, faça *commit* sempre, nunca reescreva o histórico", bem como da escola "Mantenha seu repositório central limpo". A escolha é inteiramente sua.