# Quais seriam as práticas recomendadas para commits no Git?

Tags: git, commit

Existem práticas recomendadas para realizar *commits* e escrever comentários nesses *commits*, para uma melhor comunicação e entendimento durante o processo de desenvolvimento de software?

Comment: Ai varia, se existe algum tutorial, ou livro padronizando a atividade, e alguem souber, acredito que nao. Agora se nao houver, as responsatas serao dadas como sugestoes, assim como ocorrem com outras que nao tem uma solucao definitiva, ou exata. Se for assim, qualquer resposta para um provlema que possa ter mais de uma alternativa de resolucao serão tambem baseadas em opniao, e portanto invalidadas. Fui claro?! :D

Comment: Provavelmente será fechado esse tópico mas vou expressar minha opnião. Se você esta referindo commit ao ato de executar o comando `git commit -m "meu comentario"`. Primeiro você deve enteder o significado de commit, Commit é fazer permanentes um conjunto de mudanças e também um ato de enviar. Ou seja não acredito que exista a melhor pratica e o significado da palavra fica fácil, ao dar o commit no git você deve comentar quais mudanças no determinado documento ocorreu.

Comment: Ou o camarada quando realiza alguma alteração so coloca:

 git commit   -m "Mechi em alguma coisa ae e tela voltou a abrir, qualquer duvida fala comigo!"

Comment: Ele perguntou sobre comentários, não da quantidade de tarefa por commit. A propósito, [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17503/3117) tem uma pergunta sobre a quantidade de informação por commit.

Comment: Não falei a quantidade de tarefa por commit, mas sim que é uma prática colocar e descrever uma tarefa por commit, ou seja, respondi com exatidão a pergunta, pois a descrição a cada commit seria referente à uma tarefa. Fui obrigado a fazer desta forma por não haver pontos o suficientes para comentar.

Comment: Esclarecendo: A cada commit seria a descrição referente à tarefa que foi dado commit.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Granularidade dos *commits*

Como já respondi [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17511/227), a principal boa prática é tentar comitar uma funcionalidade por vez, independente se alterou um ou 10 arquivos. Dessa forma seria possível reverter uma mudança em caso de problemas, o que não é tão raro quanto se pensa.

Note que alteração em muitos arquivos ao mesmo tempo é sintoma de que poderia dividir a alteração em partes.

## Comentários

Não sou a favor de grandes explicações em comentários de *commits*.

O que recomendo é uma explicação em alto nível de no máximo uma linha do que foi feito, como uma nota mental, a partir da qual o desenvolvedor possa lembrar-se ou pelo menos procurar a especificação daquela mudança.

## Conteúdo do comentário

Algo usado em praticamente todas as empresas que levam o processo a sério, seja ele ágil ou tradicional, é vincular cada *commit* a um *ticket* ou *issue* de algum sistema como o Jira, Mantis ou Bugzilla.

Cada *ticket* é, por sua vez, vinculado a uma tarefa específica ou a toda uma estória de usuário, dependendo também da granularidade em que o projeto está planejado.

Assim, o desenvolvedor pode facilmente consultar a documentação e possível discussão sobre o *bug* ou funcionalidade. Também é possível rastrear no sistema de gerenciamento de versões quais foram as alterações necessárias para implementar a funcionalidade `X`.

## Auxílio de ferramentas

A maioria das IDEs possui integração com as ferramentas de *tickets* e, configuradas corretamente, são capazes de adicionar automaticamente ao comentário do *commit* o número do *ticket* em que o desenvolvedor está trabalhando.

Também é possível configurar uma regra no sistema de versionamento para impedir que *commits* sejam feitos sem comentários e sem vínculo com algum *ticket* cadastrado.

Em geral não recomendo tal nível de controle, mas é algo comum em grandes empresas para evitar que desenvolvedores inexperientes façam *commits* indevidos.

Comment: Obrigado!! E obrigado pela Resposta!!

Comment: @TiagoAmaral De nada! Só uma coisa, vi que você aceitou minha resposta como certa muito rapidamente, mas considere também a do Gabe. Minha resposta foi geral, baseada na vivência em empresas, a do Gabe é mais focada no Git e na documentação oficial.

Comment: Sim vou dar uma olhada. Aceitei pois não acreditava que poderiam surgir mais respostas, devido a um certo grau de rejeição de outros usuários.

Comment: @TiagoAmaral Não dê muita importância às desavenças e discórdia em torno de uma pergunta. O site ainda é novo, e muita coisa continua sendo discutida. Sempre tem gente disposta a ajudar. E o mesmo vale se você quiser responder uma pergunta... Se achar que consegue ajudar alguém, melhor fazê-lo do que ficar debatendo se a dúvida tem mérito.

Answer (score 18):

A [documentação "oficial"](http://www.git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1/Git-Distribu%C3%ADdo-Contribuindo-Para-Um-Projeto#Diretrizes-de-Commit)<sup>1</sup> do git tem um recomendações sobre commits e mensagens. São um conjunto de boas práticas pra tornar a nevegação pelo hitórico do projeto mais fácil de assimilar.

Apesar de não serem obrigatórias, elas são fartamente aplicadas e replicadas pela internet:

1. **Verifique problemas de whitespace no código**
   Essa é fácil, só executar `git diff --check` antes do commit, e qualquer erro de espaçamento extra vai ser listado.
2. **Commits devem ser mudanças pequenas e completas no código**
   Duas coisas para se ter em mente é que um commit deve sempre funcionar sozinho. Se você implementou uma funcionalidade que levou 20 commits, cada um deles deve adicionar (ou remover) uma parte de maneira completa, e o programa deve continuar totalmente funcional. Isso não significa que os commits devem ser enormes, contendo centenas de linhas alteradas ao longo de dias. Procure fazer mudanças pequenas e incrementais.
3. **Formato da mensagem**<sup>2</sup>
   Essa é uma parte tão essencial quanto as outras. Um projeto que mantém o mesmo padrão de mensagens é mais fácil de entender e acompanhar. Não faz muito sentido ser a única pessoa do projeto a trabalhar assim... Se você conseguir que todo mundo escreva as mensagens nesse formato, tudo vai ser mais fácil:

   1. Espaçamento de 1 linha entre o título do commit e o resto da mensagem
   2. O título deve ter no máximo 50 caracteres
   3. O título deve começar com letra maiúscula
   4. O título não deve terminar com '.'
   5. O título deve estar no presente da segunda pessoa:
      Ao invés de "*Eu adicionei testes para*" ou "*Adicionando testes para*", use "*Adiciona testes para*"
   6. Corpo da mensagem não deve ter largura maior que 72 caracteres
   7. Corpo da mensagem deve explicar *o que* e *por que*, não *como*.

   O exemplo na documentação do git:

   ```
   Breve (50 caracteres ou menos) resumo das mudanças

   Texto explicativo mais detalhado, se necessário. Separe em linhas de
   72 caracteres ou menos. Em alguns contextos a primeira linha é
   tratada como assunto do e-mail e o resto como corpo. A linha em branco
   separando o resumo do corpo é crítica (a não ser que o corpo não seja
   incluído); ferramentas como rebase podem ficar confusas se você usar
   os dois colados.

   Parágrafos adicionais vem após linhas em branco.

    - Tópicos também podem ser usados

    - Tipicamente um hífen ou asterisco é utilizado para marcar tópicos,
      precedidos de um espaço único, com linhas em branco entre eles, mas
      convenções variam nesse item
   ```

A dica final é que, se você registrar um editor default pro git com `git config --global core.editor vim` (por exemplo), é provável que o git inicie o editor com as configurações de formatação carregadas, pra te avisar caso você fuja do formato.

---

<sup><sup>1.</sup> A documentação no [git-scm.com](http://www.git-scm.com) é derivada de um livro que não foi escrito pelos autores do git, mas para todos os efeitos é considerada a documentação oficial. A versão em Português está defasada, mas essa parte não mudou muita coisa.</sup>

<sup><sup>2.</sup> A lista de itens da formatação é derivada de [How to Write a Git Commit Message](http://chris.beams.io/posts/git-commit) (Como Escrever uma Mensagem de Commit - em Inglês). Eu gosto da maneira como a lista está organizada, por isso usei. Mas ela segue todas as recomendações da documentação oficial</sup>